# Is there any method to develop an ODE for a hydraulic system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, physics, classical-mechanics

If I have a hydraulic system like this:

[image]

- $d(t)$ is disturbance in force
- $p(t)$ is the pressure in bar
- $y_1(t)$ is the length in meters
- $y_2(t$ is the other length in meters

Which method should I use to develop an ODE for a hydraulic system?

I have tried diffrent ways but I allways end up in wrong solution. Here is what I have been tried.

- Lagrangian mechanics - How should I apply pressure-energy $p(t)$ and disturbance-energy $d(t)$ ?
- Newtonian mechanics - How should I take regard of pressurefall and non-stiffness(as you see, the system have no spring, which means that the cylinder can go to infinity in theory. There is no limit in this system).
- Analogy with RLC circut - How should a write down a RLC circut of this system? I know that the mass would be the coil(Inductance), the resistor whould be damping and the cacaptitor whould be stiffness

$$L\ddot{y} + R\dot{y} + Cy = 0$$

Is the classic formula from:

$$L\dot{y} + Ry + C\int y = 0$$

So what do you think? Which method should I use? I'm not asking you to solve this for me. I'm only asking for guidance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us more about your setup: 1) What is $p(t)$? I have no idea what *pressure-energy* is. 2) What is $d(t)$? I have no idea what you mean by *disturbance-energy.* 3) What other assumptions do you make? Do the pistons move without friction? Is there hydrostatic pressure? Can the green liquid be assumed to always have the same pressure? — Also: Why didn’t you ask this on [physics.se]?

Comment: Hi! I don't know if there is a pressure-energy and disturbance-energy. I'm not allowed to ask questions in Physics because the mods there think it's better that I asking my techincal questions here insted of asking in both Math and Physics. If you want to make a mathematical model of a linear hydraulic system. What method would you use then? @Wrzlprmft

Comment: *I'm not allowed to ask questions in Physics because the mods there think it's better that I asking my techincal questions here insted of asking in both Math and Physics.* – I sincerely doubt that that’s the reason. Anyway, should you be question-banned on Physics, this is no excuse to start asking off-topic questions here.

Comment: *I don't know if there is a pressure-energy and disturbance-energy.* – Then why do they appear in your diagram? What do these symbols ($p$ and $d$) represent? At the very least, please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Well. I don't know what to do. I didn't break any rule there. Perhaps the other uses dislike my questions so much because they want to punish me for I'm new there. I don't know.

Comment: Well, $p$ is the pressure in bar and $d$ is the dusturbance in force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write down the forces acting on each piston and add them up. The net force is what is accelerating your piston. This gives you second-order differential equations, which you then can translate to first-order differential equations and solve.

A few hints:

- Do you assume the blue liquid to be incompressible? If yes, what does this mean for $y_1$ and $y_2$?
- How would the forces change if $y_1$ and $y_2$ were different?
- If you ignore hydrostatic pressure, what’s the pressure of the green liquid?
- Does it matter where the mass $M$ is attached?

Comment: Thank you. Yes. They are compressed. But I have a question who might solve my problem. I need a spring into the cylinder. But is it possible to model the system without springs?

Comment: I fail to make sense of your comment. Springs are not a modelling tool; of course it is possible to model the system without them. If you have a real spring that you want to model, that’s just another force.

Comment: I found the answer now! I need to take the derivative of the second order system. So it will be a first order system. The second order will give me the position, but the first oder will give me the veolocity.